# Algorithm telling if a word is good

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursion, computability, recursive-algorithms

Consider the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. A word is a finite sequence of letters. A word is called basic if it's of one of the following forms: $1^k0, 1^k00, 1^k000,1^k0000,1^k00000$; where $1^k=11\dots11$ ($k$ times). A word is called good if it's a finite sequence of basic words. So for example the word $10111000110000$ is good but the words $1,1111, 0,000,01,1000000$ are not good. A good word must start with $1$, end with $0$, and it cannot contain more than five $0$s in a row in it.

I've been trying to come up with a program for a register machine that accepts a word in register 1 and, if the word is good, it gives 1 in register 1; otherwise it gives 0 in register 1.

The syntax is as follows:

- add1 reg - Append "1" onto register 'reg'
- add0 reg - Append "0" onto register 'reg'
- jump  n - Jump forward by 'n' instructions
- jumpb n - Jump backward by 'n' instructions
- case  n - perform a case operation on register number n
- goto  name - Jump to line identified by 'name'
- label name - Identifies a line as 'name'

"case n" works as follows.

If register n is empty, we go to the very next instruction.

If the first symbol of register n is 1, we delete that symbol and go to the second instruction after the case instruction.

If the first symbol of register n is 0, we delete that symbol and go to the third instruction after the case instruction.

---

I only have some idea how to partially implement this. For example let's how we can account for the case when more than five $0$s are followed by $1$ (in which case the word is not good). Perform cases on register 1.

If it's empty, append 1 to register 1 and end the program.

If the first symbol in register 1 is 0, then add 1 to register 2.

If the first symbol is 1, we add 111111 to register 3 and compare it with what is written in register 2. If registers 2 and 3 have same stuff in it, then this means that the word on which the program is running is not good (it contains more than 5 zeros in a row).

This is just some idea but of course it's incomplete and I don't know how to account for other cases. Even if there were no other cases, the program corresponding to this idea needs modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with register machines before, but I think the following is a quick and dirty way of doing this, using only a single register. Let me know if I've made any errors.

```
case 1
goto failure
goto one
goto failure

label one
case 1
goto failure
goto one
goto zero1

label zero1
case 1
goto success
goto one
goto zero2

label zero2
case 1
goto success
goto one
goto zero3

label zero3
case 1
goto success
goto one
goto zero4

label zero4
case 1
goto success
goto one
goto zero5

label zero5
case 1
goto success
goto one

label failure
case 1
goto bad
goto failure
goto failure

label bad
add0 1
goto end

label success
add1 1

label end
```

Comment: At first glance it outputs 0 if the input is the good word 100000. I'll look more carefully into it.

Comment: @user700016 You're not wrong. I've edited.